# How to implement the way to send a friend request in XMPPFramework in iOS?

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I have already figured the way to accept a subscription request in XMPPRoster using the following in **MainAppDelegate.m**:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
    {
     NSString *presenceType = [presence type];
     if  ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"subscribe"]) {
       [xmppRoster acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:[presence from] andAddToRoster:YES];
   }
```

However, I am not able to send a friend request on a button click. The main problem I am facing is that my New Friend add form is in a separate **ViewController.m** class than **MainAppDelegate.m**. How do I access the XMPPRoster methods from **ViewController.m**? Do I have to redeclare the object for XMPPRoster or can I somehow reuse the object already instantiated in **MainAppDelegate.m** file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be sufficient to reuse the already existing XMPPRoster object. For that you could write a custom init-method for your ViewController.m, e.g.

```
    - initWithRoster:(XMPPRoster *)roster
    {
       self = [super initWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil];
       ...
    }
```

and then assign the roster to an instance variable or property of ViewController. It is possible then to access the XMPPRoster object when the view is loading and loaded.

Alternatively you could just add an XMPPRoster property to ViewController and assign the roster object from MainAppDelegate after the view controller is instantiated but before the controller is displayed. Yet I prefer the first solution.

Comment: I tried instantiating an object of **MainAppDelegate** inside **ViewController** like this:

    `MainAppDelegate *myappdelegate = [[MainAppDelegate alloc] init];
    [myappdelegate.xmppRoster subscribePresenceToUser:(XMPPJID *)friendID];`  

but, it didn't work. Also, could you kindly explain how the roster object that you created in the first solution is linked to the XMPPRoster object instantiated in **MainAppDelegate.m** ?

Comment: The MainAppDelegate object you created inside ViewController is not the same as the runtime AppDelegate that is instantiated when the App launches. If you want to access the app delegate from within the ViewController you have to use the following: `(MainAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`.

When you have already created a first XMPPRoster object in the MainAppDelegate and your ViewController has a property `@property (nonatomic) XMPPRoser *roster` that is declared in the interface file, you can simply assign the XMPPRoster instance created in the MainAppDelegate.